# "Return of a Function() in PHP" skip syntex error in filter_var()

Tags: php, function, syntax-error, return-value

```
private function getURL(){
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url'] != "" ? $_GET['url'] : "home";
    return explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/")),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
}
```

The above code execute without any warning or error, but the second line of getURL() function should be like: return explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/"),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

Why I did not get any error or warning?

Please let me know, what is happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parenthesis are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

explode is called with three arguments:

1. The delimiter: `"/"`
2. The string to split: `filter_var(trim($url,"/"))`
3. An additional parameter: `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`

In this case, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL is being passed as the limit parameter, which expects an integer. Since FILTER_SANITIZE_URL is a constant and not an integer, it's not being used as intended here.

However, PHP is lenient and doesn't throw an error. Instead, it likely casts the constant to an integer (which may result in a limit of 0 or some other unintended value) and proceeds with the execution.